# How to add new table in Visual Studio 2010(Services Based Database)?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with my database, I can't add a new table - See screenshot below of the error message:

Can anyone help me? thanks a lot...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bB1m.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot your issue,Install (or reinstall) Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Comment: thanks a lot... i did it.. just download service pack 1 for VS2010 then choose remove... then fix the problem :)